# Can Fiddler .SAZ capture files be combined?

Tags: file, save, fiddler

Fiddler has an autosave feature which unfortunately clears the captured sessions each time it saves to an .SAZ. Rather than have a folder of Fiddler save sessions (.SAZ's), I'd prefer to have one master .SAZ, albeit saved at regular intervals.

Since there doesn't appear to be an option in Fiddler to do this, is there a way to combine or merge .SAZ files?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use the Fiddler UI: When you execute the menu command "Load Archive..." you can append the data from the loaded SAZ file to the current session list. Therefore it is possible to load multiple SAZ files and them save them into a new SAZ file.
2. Use Fiddler Core: Using Fiddler Core you can develop an own .net program that merges multiple SAZ files into one new SAZ file. The methods of loading and saving sessions is pretty simple:

   ```
    using Fiddler;

    Session[] oLoaded1 = Utilities.ReadSessionArchive("FileToLoad1.saz", false);
    Session[] oLoaded2 = Utilities.ReadSessionArchive("FileToLoad2.saz", false);
    Session[] oAllSessions = ... //<merge the two arrays>
    Utilities.WriteSessionArchive("Combined.saz", oAllSessions, null, false);
   ```

Sources:

- http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo
- [Utilities.ReadSessionArchive](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/om/html/EC74A2B.htm)
- [Utilities.WriteSessionArchive](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/om/html/86E7E7F6.htm)